# Difficulty displaying a 2D array using PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Been researching this for an hour. I give up.  I'm trying to create an array after populating the array from a MySQL table.

I then want to output the array text elements across the top of a table (table headings)

```
$sqlRotations="SELECT id, rotationName FROM sched_rotations";
$resultRotations=mysql_query($sqlRotations);
$arrayRotations = array();
while($row_Rotation=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultRotations)){ 
  $arrayRotations[]=$row_Rotation;
}
```

...then I'm trying to print out the "rotationName" as table column headings:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?
foreach( $arrayRotations as $key => $value){
echo "<td>Id: $key, Rotation:". $arrayRotations[$value]." </td>";
}
?>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the following output in < t d > format:

Id: 0, Rotation:    Id: 1, Rotation:    Id: 2, Rotation:    Id: 3, Rotation:    Id: 4, Rotation:    Id: 5, Rotation:    Id: 6, Rotation:    Id: 7, Rotation:    Id: 8, Rotation:    Id: 9, Rotation:    Id: 10, Rotation:

---

Furthermore if I change the for key value echo to this:

```
foreach( $arrayRotations as $key => $value){
echo "<td>Id: $key, Rotation:". $value." </td>";
```

}

then I get this output:

Id: 0, Rotation:Array   Id: 1, Rotation:Array   Id: 2, Rotation:Array   Id: 3, Rotation:Array   Id: 4, Rotation:Array   Id: 5, Rotation:Array   Id: 6, Rotation:Array   Id: 7, Rotation:Array   Id: 8, Rotation:Array   Id: 9, Rotation:Array   Id: 10, Rotation:Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Rotation</th>
</tr>
<?php 
foreach($arrayRotations as $rotation)
{
   printf("<tr><td>%s</td> <td>%s</td></tr>", $rotation['id'], $rotation['rotationName');
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `foreach()` array incorrectly.

```
<?php
foreach($arrayRotations as $line){
   echo "<td>Id: " . $line['id'] . ' Rotation: '. $line['rotationName'] . '</td>';
}
?>
```